# Git, can I have a setup without local repo?

Tags: git, repo

Regarding to local repo/remote repo model of Git, I wonder if there is a way to set up Git environment so it does not have(need) a local repo at all? It will help for the case we do not need all the members of the team to get to be familiar with Git's two repo model and we always guarantee the connections to our repo on the server(remote repo).

Comment: What should those team members be able to do? Any hosted Git has a web interface where they can view the files on the remote. If they want to have the files locally, they'll have to clone, and successively pull updates.

Comment: To make it clear, we want to simplify the usage of Git which is a bit road blocker for new starters. In stead of "git checkout develop", I found we can also do "git checkout origin/develop". So it makes me wonder if we are able to commit directly into origin/develop(so we can skip the local commit and push steps).

Comment: If you want to simplify things for your new developers, why dont you just make shell scripts for them to run instead? 'git checkout develop' would be 'get_develop.sh' and it would "do the right thing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is, no, it doesn't work like that.

`origin/develop` is a remote ref, not a branch. Remote references in a local repo are just a note of where each branch was the last time you communicated with that remote. These are read only from a user perspective.

If you attempt to check out origin/develop as you suggest, git will check out the commit that reference points to, but because there is no local branch, the checkout will have a detached head. In order to commit in any meaningful way, you'll need to create a branch. Note you'll get this warning if you attempt this:

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
```

If you don't get this error you have a local branch in a local origin namespace. I had a co-worker who tried to do this by attempting to create a branch on the remote like this:

```
# THIS IS NOT GOOD CODE DO NOT USE
git branch origin/branch
# THIS IS NOT GOOD CODE DO NOT USE
```

Which creates a local branch named origin/branch, not a branch on origin. He just about went crazy because he was updating origin/branch and it wasn't showing up in GitHub.

Comment: I got the warning. Now another question, can we suggest Git do such new feature to make it possible to make "origin/develop"(the real one) a real branch?

Comment: @M2014 Probably not, this feature would run contrary to the core design of git. As a distributed VCS, git is designed so that no single repository is inherently more important than any other and every repository is complete and autonomous. This feature is a staple of centralized VCS. For a good overview of the basic types, you can read the [About Version Control](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) section of the Pro Git Book.